# Obtain first paragraph of channel entry text field

Tags: wysiwyg

Is there an easy way to get the first paragraph of a wysiwyg. In this instance I want to add it without the enclosing `<p>` tags into a Facebook `og:description` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I used the hacksaw plugin:

`{exp:eehive_hacksaw cutoff="</p>"}{copy}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}`

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but just NSM Better Meta or just a plain text-field in your field-group would have been cleaner IMO.

Comment: Yeah, this would include any HTML in the field, as well as images, tables, etc. And a WYSIWYG field doesn't necessarily have to contain any paragraphs. I'd suggest adding a plain textarea field for the Description. Or using an SEO plugin like SEO Lite.